# Multi-particle Hamiltonian for the free Klein-Gordon field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, klein-gordon-equation

The text I am reading (Peskin and Schroeder) gives the Hamiltonian for the free Klein-Gordon field as:
$$H=\int {d^3 p\over (2\pi)^3}\; E_p\; a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a_{\vec p}$$
This does not seem to be good for multi-particle states. How would this Hamiltonian be modified for multi-particle states?

Comment: "This does not seem to be good for multi particle states" -- 1. What do you mean by that? 2. Why do you think so?

Comment: @TobiasFünke It seems to me that an expectation value would never yield a sum over multiple energies for a state like $|\vec p, \vec q\rangle$. Would the expectation value not be $E_p+E_q$.

Comment: Again: Why do you think so?

Comment: Thanks guys, I understand what you are trying to do, but honestly, if I could answer all of these questions I wouldnt be asking here. I work in isolation and usually figure everything out myself after long enough. Guess I will have to keep grinding at it.

Comment: What do you mean? Of course, understanding these kinds of things is not easy and takes a lot of time and practice. Take another textbook, to start with, if P&S is too hard right now. Also, there are many online lecture notes, lectures on YouTube etc. Despite all that, I simply asked you for the reason of your claims. Write down a calculation to show why you think what you say. You cannot just make more or less random guesses/claims and then expect us to sort everything out for you.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Give me this bit: the Hamiltonian as I have written in my post, is it the one we will use onthe general Fock space?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus Yes, it is the one we will use on the general Fock space to describe the free QED EM field. It is an appropriate second-quantized Hamiltonian that yields the correct results regardless of how many particles are in the state of interest.

Comment: Your term $a^{\dagger}_p a_p$ is the number density operator in $p$ space. Its integral simply yields the total number of particles. There is no problem with having more than one particle with momentum $p$ since photons are bosons. That they are bosons is why we use the commutation relations rather than the anticommutation relations. This makes us able to put more than one particle of the same momentum in a state. For example $a^{\dagger}_pa^{\dagger}_p|0\rangle$ is not zero. This is related to your other question you recently posted.

Comment: Using the commutation relations you should figure out the action of $\hat N = \int d^3q a^\dagger_{\vec q} a_{\vec q}$ on the state $a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}|0\rangle$ and see what you get. (Hint: you will get the number two. I.e., $\hat Na^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}|0\rangle = 2 a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}|0\rangle$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$H=\int {d^3 p\over (2\pi)^3}\; E_p\; a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a_{\vec p}\tag{1}$$
> This does not seem to be good for multi-particle states.

It is perfectly fine for multi-particle states.

> How would this Hamiltonian be modified for multi-particle states?

It does not need to be modified.

---

For example, consider the two-particle state:
$$
|\vec p_1, \vec p_2\rangle\equiv a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_1}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_2}|0\rangle\;,
$$
and, if you please, the values of $p_1$ and $p_2$ can be the same.

The action of the Hamiltonian in Eq. (1) is:
$$
\hat H|\vec p_1, \vec p_2\rangle
$$
$$
=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} E_p 
a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}a_{\vec p}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_1}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_2}|0\rangle
$$
$$
=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} E_p 
a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}[a_{\vec p},a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_1}a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_2}]|0\rangle
$$
$$
=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} E_p 
a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}
\left(
[a_{\vec p},a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_1}]a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_2}
+a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_1}[a_{\vec p},a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_2}]
\right)|0\rangle\;.
$$

Then use:
$$
[a_{\vec p}, a_{\vec q}^\dagger] = (2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec p - \vec q)
$$
to see that:
$$
\hat H|\vec p_1, \vec p_2\rangle
$$
$$
\int d^3 p E_p 
a^{\dagger}_{\vec p}
\left(
\delta^3(\vec p - \vec p_1)a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_2}
+a^{\dagger}_{\vec p_1}\delta^3(\vec p - \vec p_2)
\right)|0\rangle
$$
$$
=(E_{\vec p_1} + E_{\vec p_2})|\vec p_1, \vec p_2\rangle\;.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Take e.g. the two-particle state $|\vec{p}_1,\vec{p}_2\rangle=a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_1} a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}|0\rangle$. Using the commutation relation $$[a_{\vec{p}}, a^\dagger_{\vec{q}}]=(2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}- \vec{q})$$ and $a_{\vec{p}}|0\rangle=0$, one finds $$\begin{align}
a^\dagger_{\vec{p}} a_{\vec{p}} a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_1} a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}|0\rangle
 &=a^\dagger_{\vec{p}} \left(a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_1} a_{\vec{p}} + (2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p} -\vec{p}_1)\right) a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}|0\rangle \\&= a^\dagger_{\vec{p}} a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_1} \left(a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}a_{\vec{p}}+(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p} -\vec{p}_2)\right)|0\rangle+ (2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}- \vec{p}_1)a^\dagger_{\vec{p}}a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}|0\rangle \\&=(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}- \vec{p}_2)a^\dagger_{\vec{p}}a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_1}|0\rangle+(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec{p}-\vec{p}_1)a^\dagger_{\vec{p}} a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}|0\rangle.\end{align}  $$ It is now easy to compute $$ \begin{align} H|\vec{p}_1,\vec{p}_2\rangle &=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} E_{\vec{p}}a^\dagger_{\vec{p}}a_{\vec{p}}|\vec{p}_1,\vec{p}_2\rangle \\ &= (E_{\vec{p}_1}+E_{\vec{p}_2})|\vec{p}_1, \vec{p}_2 \rangle, \end{align}$$ where $[a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_1}, a^\dagger_{\vec{p}_2}]=0$ was used.